# Linear Extension Principle

Tags: linear-algebra

We had the following statement in linear algebra: Let V and W vector spaces over a field k, $B=\{v_i \}_{i \in I}$ a basis of V. Let $w_i\in W$ for an arbitrary $i\in I$. Then there exists a unique linear map $\varphi :V\to W,\; \varphi(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i \in I$.

Is there no problem because the dimension of V could be infinity?

Comment: If the basis means Hamel basis, there is no problem.

Comment: No, there's no problem.

Comment: thanks. I find the proof now

Comment: @Woodface Besides the fact that Hamel Basis is more usually used for $\;\Bbb R_{\Bbb Q}\;$ , what can be a basis which is *not* Hamel? And how would this affect the outcome?

Comment: @Timbuc  If you have a question, ask it using Ask Question button.

Comment: @Woodface Thanks for the tip. What I meant is that I don't think the basis being Hamel or not has anything to do with the fact that the function can be linearly extended to the whole space.